# Accidentally deleted /typo3temp

Tags: typo3, delete-directory

...now the backend doesn't work anymore.
I've recreated the folder and let the Install Tool create the subfolders but that din't help.

*What to do?*

It's T3 7.2

Comment: Check the folder's permissions, set it the same as i.e. fileadmin/user_uploads (or 777 if not sure) and also user/group - deleting whole _content_ of typo3temp should not be a problem, but maybe it requires higher perms

Comment: Don't use permissions `0777` on `typo3temp` in production, the folder also contains cached code, so you would open up the site for easy attacks by other users on the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I used the backup function of the host and it worked fine.

Thanks for the help though.